# AxiosError: Post request on Laravel app from Vue app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I need advice with Axios, and how to send a request from domain A to domain B.

- Domain A: **test.fkbraxy.sk** (Only Vue 3)
- Domain B: **app.fkbraxy.sk** (Only Laravel 10)

## Domain A:

Route api (routes/api.php) :

```
Route::post('post-contact', function (Request $request): SentMessage {
    return Mail::to(Settings::first()->email_receive)->send(new ContactFormMail($request));
});
```

## Domain B

Script on contact page:

```
data() {
    useMeta({
      title: 'Kontaktujte nás'
    })
    return {
      form: {
        name: null,
        email: null,
        mobile: null,
        msg: null
      },

      success: false,
      error: false,
      loading: false,
      errors: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    postForm() {
      if (!this.checkForm()) return false

      this.loading = true
      this.errors = []

      axios.post('https://app.fkbraxy.sk/public/api/post-contact', this.form)
        .then((res) => {
          this.success = true
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.success = false
          this.errors.push('Nepodarilo sa spojiť so serverom. Skontrolujte či všetky povinné polia boli správne vyplnené.')
          console.log(error)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading = false
        })
    },
```

**Sending works, mail is sent without error. But it always throws an error in the console:**

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 500",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at Wh (https://test.fkbraxy.sk/assets/index-a833590d.js:10:1042)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.g (https://test.fkbraxy.sk/assets/index-a833590d.js:10:4229)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "https://app.fkbraxy.sk/public/api/post-contact",
        "data": "{\"name\":\"sdfsdf\",\"email\":\"sfdsfsd@ads.asd\",\"mobile\":null,\"msg\":\"asdas dasd asd asd asd asdasd \"}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE",
    "status": 500
}
```

it shows an error after sending .catch(error)

I will be grateful for any advice, and I apologize for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 is a backend error.  The issue is your return statement.

```
return Mail::to(...)->send(...)
```

The Mail::send() method doesn't return anything so it's not valid to return to the frontend as a response. Do something like this instead.

```js
Mail::to(...)->send(...)

if (Mail::failures()) {
  return Mail::failures();
}

return 'Success';
```

Of course you can return any message, or view, or redirect, etc.